# Codeigniter / Pagination / uri_to_assoc()

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to paginate through a list of products which are searched for by defining various uri segments passed through to a single controller function browse().  Using CI's uri_to_assoc() I am building up a list of key pairs passed through to a SQL query.  However I am having real difficulties trying to get my head around how the pagination on this could work.  I'll give a few examples which will hopefully illustrate my problem.

I want to be able to browse products listed on my site by category, brand or range.  A user should be able to browse any combination of these 3 search elements such as:

- http://mysite.com/our-products/browse = browse all
- http://mysite.com/our-products/browse/category/cabinets+%26+storage - list products from the category Cabinets & Storage
- http://mysite.com/our-products/browse/category/cabinets+%26+storage/brands/ramon+soler - list products from the category Cabinets & Storage where brand is Ramon Soler
- http://mysite.com/our-products/browse/category/cabinets+%26+storage/range/texas - list products from the category Cabinets & Storage where range is Texas
- http://mysite.com/our-products/browse/brand/ramon+soler/range/texas - list products from the brand Ramon Soler where range is Texas
- etc etc...

The problem is when it comes to pagination, CI always adds this to the end of the url.  So depending on the depth of the query the position of the offset parameter in the url varies.

Anyone any ideas how to introduce the offset segment into this format so I always know exactly where it is regardless of which every combination of link use from above?  Also remember than on the first load of these pages no offset segment will be set at all and will only be present on subsequent page loads.

I'd prefer not to have to use query strings if possible and stick to a url segment based approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see your current code that deals with the pagination? Not sure why you need to "always know exactly where it is" if you're using uri_to_assoc, just use something like `page/4`. If you show us how you have it configured (your actual code) that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Always add the offset to the end of the page, and then retrieve it with:

```
 $offset = (int) end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

The typecast provides you with 0 if not a valid offset (so you have a base offset).

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: But when I do this and pull this into an array the offset become the key   `Array ( [category] => test [brand] => vasic+home [24] => )`

Comment: @AdrianWalls: Why is that a problem? Can we please see your current code? You aren't just dumping the whole URL into a MySQL query without checking it first, are you? Only issue I see here is that the URL will look weird with a number dangling on the end, and that it might return `1` is there is a text value (remember, the address bar is user input, subject to the same scrutiny as any other).